# "Strength" of detected blob

Tags: opencv

I am following this tutorial at http://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/ to detect blobs using a SimpleBlobDetector http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html

From all the blobs I obtained, how do I keep the best blob ? i.e. the blob that best resembles a circle. The output of the blob detector are keypoints with response as its attribute but I dont think it is being utilized in the blob detector.

I hope I can receive some help on this. In the meantime, I shall read up on the source code of the blob detector and hopefully be able to figure out what/where to edit to get what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In python:

```
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
# Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.1
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
```

In C++

```
// Setup SimpleBlobDetector parameters.
SimpleBlobDetector::Params params;
// Filter by Circularity
params.filterByCircularity = true;
params.minCircularity = 0.1;
Ptr<SimpleBlobDetector> detector = SimpleBlobDetector::create(params);
```

In the vector `keypoints`, the one that is most similar to a circle will be the last one, since the circularity of a circle is 1 while other shapes have circularity <1

You'll find a full tutorial [here](http://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/).
This, btw, is the same page you're looking at... Keep scrolling down...